# Difference in using arguments object directly and indirectly?

Tags: javascript, filter, arguments

I wrote two versions of a function that is sent an array, followed by one or more arguments. The function removes all elements from the array that are of the same value as these arguments. The only difference between the two versions is that the `arguments` object is used directly in one and indirectly in the other.

**`arguments` used directly:**

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var result = arr.filter(function(value) {       
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i] == value) return;      
        }
        return value;   
    });
    return result; 
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);  // returns [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

**`arguments` used indirectly:**

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = arguments;
    var result = arr.filter(function(value) {       
        for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] == value) return;   
        }       
        return value;   
    });
    return result; 
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);  // returns [1, 1]
```

Why is there a difference in the returned array?

Comment: In the first function, the `arguments` value is relevant to the `.filter()` callback function. The `arguments` object is created for each function invocation.

Comment: As Pointy says, the functions use different *arguments* objects.

Comment: Why do you guys put answers into comments rather than into answers?

Comment: @Pointy, ah! I totally missed that. Thank you. I wasn't using `arguments` indirectly, but rather an entirely different `arguments` object.